# Fundamental Solution for 1d heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

So this question says to take $u(x,t) = v(x^2/t)$ to solve the 1d heat equation.  That is,
$$
u_t = u_{xx}
$$
and it gives the general solution in the form 
$$
v(z) = c\int_{0}^z e^{-s/4}s^{-1/2} ds + d
$$
(you can verify that this indeed is a solution to the heat equation).  Anyway, the question involves choosing $c$ such that this solution is the fundamental solution, so that the initial condition $\Phi(x,0) = \delta(x)$ holds.  I'm not sure how to go about doing this, can you perhaps point me in the right direction?

I think that $c$ solves
$$
c = \frac{1}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s^2/4t}\left(\frac{s^2}{t}\right)^{-1/2} ds }
$$
Can someone verify this/explain why this?

Answer (score 2):

The heat equation (also known as diffusion equation) conserves *total mass*, which by definition is the integral $M (t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,t)\,dx$. (This can be proved by taking time derivative of $M$ and using the PDE.)  Since $\delta$ is a *unit mass*,  in order to satisfy $u(x,0)=\delta(x)$ we need $M$ to be $1$.

This is why we normalize the fundamental solution $$u(x,t)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{t}}e^{-x^2/(4t)}$$
so that its mass is $1$. Which leads to
$$c^{-1} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/4}\,dt =\sqrt{4\pi}$$
Above, the mass is  computed   at time $t=1$ and equated to $1$. It could be computed in any other moment $t_0>0$; the result is the same.

Comment: Shouldn't the last integral, be an integral over space and not time?